# Simple image editor, to draw translucent lines, for Debian Gnu/Linux

Tags: drawing

I am regularly taking screen-shots, and wanting to highlight a part of the screen. With for example translucent yellow.

I have several images editors, some can draw using translucent colours, by drawing to another layer, and setting transparency of the layer. However these are harder to use, and take to long to load. Some are quick to load and use, but don't seem to (as far as I can tell) have translucent colours.

What programs have this feature: load image, pick a translucent colour, draw over image, save (or better copy to clip board)?

I don't need to be able to save multiple layers. It needs to save in a format that can be used in google slides.

The sniping tool in MS-Windows does exactly what I need (I finally found something that MS-Windows is better at.).

OS: Debian Gnu/Linux.

Comment: For which operating systems? -- Should the newly added layers be editable after closing the editor, and repoening the file? Or are you fine with "flattening" all layers into a single pixel-graphics file after saving?

Answer (score 2):

Someone told me about Flameshot.

It sits in the system tray, waiting to be activated.
It has all the features of KDE'S spectacle (at least all the ones that I use), and it has tools to sketch over the image. Including transparent highlight, arrows, lines, boxes, and more.

Here is an example of what it can do with very little training, and with little effort.

[image: Example of what flameshot can do]

When the program starts, it places a button in the system tray. Use thin to activate it. To change colour you need to click the secret right-mouse-button.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend GIMP for Linux. It's not quite as quick and convenient as the Windows Snipping tool, but I think it can come close once you get the hang of it.

Comment: I do use this sometimes. However, it does not meet the quick to load, easy to use requirements as outlined in the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about any kinds of image editors, I would recommend [this one](https://pixlr.com/x/). It's a website, so you don't have to install anything :) and it has a lot of features.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).